# How to format number with minus at right side?

Tags: xslt

How to format number with minus at right side?
I have xml:

```html
<Invoice>
<TotalAmount>890.09-</TotalAmount>
</Invoice>


<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"  version="1.0">
  <xsl:decimal-format decimal-separator="," grouping-separator="."/>
  
  <xsl:template match="/Invoice">
   <xsl:value-of select="format-number(TotalAmount, '#.###,00')"/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I think is ok but I have specific requirement, for negativs minus sign is at right side of number instead left side. How to display number in format: '#.###,00' with minus at right side. Should I read value without minus and after that append minus?
Is it better solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think removing the minus prior to the format number, and then re-appending it, might be the only way to go

Here is one way you could do that, in a single expression

```
<xsl:value-of select="concat(format-number(translate(TotalAmount, '-', ''), '#.###,00'), translate(TotalAmount, '01234567890.,', ''))"/>
```